# How to create a Virtual PDF ESC/POS Printer to make some tests while programming?

Tags: pdf, printing, odoo-8, odoo, point-of-sale

I need to send the tickets directly from the Point of Sale to an ESC/POS printer.

I was wondering if the only chance to print in a ESC/POS printer is to use the [**PosBox**](https://www.odoo.com/shop/product/pos-point-of-sale-posbox-312) to print tickets directly from Odoo or if there is another way.

> The PosBox is a little hardware box based on a Raspberry-Pi that will handle all the peripherals' drivers and setup in a very easy way

[image]

So my questions are:

- How could I create a **Virtual ESC/POS Printer**? I would like to use something similar to the Virtual PDF printer, in order to print the tickets to PDF and make some test while I am programming. Is that possible?
- What is there in the PosBox image ("Raspberry Pi Image") to make it work everything out of the box?
- If I have the ESC/POS printer correctly installed and connected to a computer with Windows System. The Odoo Server is accessed remotely from this computer. I have installed the [hw_escpos](https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/8.0/hw_escpos/) module. Could this work or the use of the PosBox is mandatory?

Answer (score 0):

I am working with PosBox so as per me if you are managing odoo remotely and your printer is attched with some our system which is not direcly connected to you odoo server so in this case you need some extra device to bridge your harware(printer) and software(odoo). So here PosBox comes in picture. Or any other device if they can compatible with both system so it is also useful. In case of your answer:

1) If you are programming and you want to check printed ticket's PDF then you can do it via your xml template file. From that you can pass arguments under **`<report>`** tag.

2) In PosBox we need to insert an image i.e. OS image so that this device can work as your CPU of your system. In that image there are some h/w modules of odoo. i.e. hw_escpos, hw_proxy, hw_scale etc. kind of hardware modules are there. Also apart from this one odoo instance is running on from that device so you can manage all data from that link.

3) If all things are connected in a single system and odoo is working remotely then no need to you PosBox to print ticket. PosBox only helpful when your printer is attached remotely in any other place and odoo is working to any other system and after this you are accessing odoo to any 3rd system and you want to print ticket where printer is connected any else system so then and then only need to use of PosBox.